# Couldn't find configuration property value for key ${mule.env} error

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

I am new to Mulesoft and setting up my first Mulesoft project in Anypoint studio and seeing this error -  Couldn't find configuration property value for key ${mule.env}

Can some one help me how to fix it?

Only solution mentioned in mulesoft website is to change the Run configuration. I changed it to some examples given and that didn't work.  This is the current value under arguments in my Project's Run configuration

-M-XX:-UseBiasedLocking -M-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -M-XX:+UseG1GC -M-XX:+UseStringDeduplication

Comment: you will have to pass this as an argument when you are running from the Studio. -Dmule.env=dev. If you are running in Anypoint platform runtime you need to define it in the runtime properties mule.env=dev

Comment: That worked @HarshaShivamurthy Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Anypoint Studio Run Configuration you can add the definition in the VM Arguments field as `-M-Dmule.env=...` or `-Dmule.env=...`. The `-M` is mandatory to define properties for Mule from the command line but it is optional in Studio.

When you are running a standalone Mule Runtime you can define the property in the conf/wrapper.conf by adding a line like:

```
wrapper.java.additional.NN=-Dmule.env=...
```

Note that `NN` should be a number that is not used in other definitions in the file.

In Runtime Manager manager in the Settings tab you can add the property by name (`mule.env`) and set its value in the UI.

For more options see the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/configuring-properties